# Is it possible to use __init__.py files to use classes in different directories ? And how?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, object

For my project, I use object-oriented Python class. I'm quite new at Python. I'm using Python 3.5.
I use those classes in different subdirectories. My files are organized that way :

```
dir
|-- MyClasses
|   |-- class1_file.py
|   |-- class2_file.py
|   ...
|-- MyPrograms1
|   |-- program_using_class1.py
|   |-- program_using_class2.py
|   ...
|-- MyPrograms2
|   ...
...
```

I was using `sys.path.append("absolute_path_to_/MyClasses")`to use my classes in the subdirectories program (for example in `MyPrograms1/program_using_class1.py`) , which was ok as long as I was working on my computer.
But now, I want to be able to run it from other computers too.

So I tried to use `__init__.py` file.
I read the Python documentation about Modules : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html .
I did not find my answer. The blank `__init__.py` did not work.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to be importing those classes as a single module by adding `__init__.py` inside the classes' directory. But instead of leaving it blank you need to import the classes:

`from . import class1_file, class2_file`

And then you'll need that directory with the classes in order to import them in another computer.

Comment: After making the __init__.py file, how do you import the classes in the program_using_class1.py for example ?

Comment: the same way you did, unless you put the class into the same directory

Comment: In `program_using_class1.py`, I wrote `from class1_file import Class1` the interpreter respond `No module named 'class1_file' `.

Comment: before importing it you must go one directory back: `from os import chdir`, `chdir('..')` and then `from class1_file import Class1`

Comment: Thank you very much, but this does not work, i've tried using the absolute path using `path.dirname()` does not work either. I tried putting `MyClasses.class1_file` instead of `class1_file` using `chdir` and the absolute path `path.dirname` did not work either. My interpreter does not seem to appreciate the relative path, I'm searching why and if the problem come from that.

Comment: `from MyClasses.class1_file import Class1`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using `sys.path.append`,`os.chdir`,`os.path.dirname` and `os.path.abspath`. 
I added the path to my module to `PYTHONPATH` using `sys.path.append` so the program could find it.

I used this code :

```
import os
import sys
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('MyClasses')
from class1_file import Class1
```

I would like to thank Stam Kaly for making me discover the `chdir` function.
You have to adapt the `os.chdir` part to your file organization.

Thank you for all the help.